# [python]how linegraph from plt.scatter?

Tags: python

```
n = 1000
count = 0
i=1

plt.xlabel("Times")
plt.ylabel("Prob")
plt.axhline(y = 0.5, c = 'r', linestyle = '--')

while i <= 1000:
    temp = np.random.choice(["H","T"],1,replace=True)
    
    if (temp == "H"):
        count = count + 1
    prob = count / i
        
    plt.scatter(i,prob,c='b')
    plt.plot(i,prob)
    
    i = i+1
    
    plt.title("Coin : p(H) = {}".format(round(prob,4))) #i=1000일때 prob
    
plt.show()
```

Result

[image]

I wrote down this code above and result from that
but i want to draw a line following points from scatter
please let me know some way

thanks

Comment: so you want a moving average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all**, you need to take the plots out of the while loop as this is inefficient.

**Secondly**, you need to construct lists for `x` and `prob` coordinates. I implement this in the loop for the purpose of example.

**Thirdly**, the probability is the final value in the `prob` list.

The rest would then look correct (it could still be tidied up quite a bit).

so this is the code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


n = 1000
count = 0
i=1

plt.xlabel("Times")
plt.ylabel("Prob")
plt.axhline(y = 0.5, c = 'r', linestyle = '--')

x = []
prob = []
while i <= 1000:
    temp = np.random.choice(["H","T"],1,replace=True)
    
    if (temp == "H"):
        count = count + 1
    x.append(i)
    prob.append(count / i)
        
    i = i+1
    
    
plt.title(f"Coin : p(H) = {round(prob[-1],4)}")
plt.scatter(x,prob,c='b')
plt.plot(x,prob, c='greenyellow')

plt.show()
```

and this is the result:

[image]